# Link embedded in mail is being clicked and user is claiming it is happening without them doing it

Tags: email

I am sending a mail that has a link which the user will click to start a process. This link is a to a REST API at our back-end. For example: https://abccorp.com/requiredApi?token=xxx123 . When the user is clicking this request we are capturing the IP address in the request. Recently user has been claiming that this link is being clicked without their knowledge. We checked the IP and it looks like it is a foreign IP. The user is saying that they have not even opened this mail.

Why would something like this be happening?

Other points to keep in mind:

1. The mails going to user are from a trusted mail server.
2. The users mail system is outside of our application scope.
3. We are using Java in our back-end and sending mail through JavaMail

Is it possible that it is due to some backlink tracking / email scanning, web crawler?

We have tried tracking all the request coming to us and their IPs and this situation is happening randomly. This is not limited to one user and also the users have identical systems.

Comment: *"Is it possible that it is due to some backlink tracking / email scanning , web crawler ?"* - it is very possible, [there was a case where gmail caches images in email "accidentally" clicking someone's analytics](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/153359587/gmail-is-clicking-sending-requests-to-links-i-ve-received-it-got-me-unsubscribed-from-a-feed?hl=en). its totally depend on client's mail client and receiving server.

Comment: Thanks , this helped a lot . @BagusTesa